# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() warning

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert json array data in mysql table. I have written this code.

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";   
    die(json_encode($response));
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

// Check connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";

if(isset($_GET['doctorJson'])){

    $json = $_GET['doctorJson'];

    $array = json_decode($json, true);

    foreach($array as $item){

        $result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT IGNORE INTO doctor_visit_track (id, doctor_name, doctor_email, date, time) VALUES 
            ('".$item['id']."', '".$item['doctorName']."', '".$item['doctorEmail']."', '".$item['date']."', '".$item['time']."')");

            }

    if($result){
        $response["message"] = "Success";
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else{
        $response["message"] = "Failure";
        echo json_encode($response);
        }
    }

mysqli_close($con);
```

Above code is working fine when I am using xampp. But when I have uploaded this code to server then same code is giving warning " Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" and not inserting in table. But using in xampp, code is working fine and inserting data successfully. Somebody help me..

Comment: `var_dump($array)` and see what you are getting.

Comment: @b0s3 I am getting NULL..

Comment: That means `$json` is not valid `JSON`. Check that.

Comment: If it helps, you can get more info on the error encountered by `json_decode()` with [`json_last_error_msg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php)

Comment: @b0s3 But why same code is successfully working when using xampp..

Comment: Check Darragh's comment

Comment: Error reporting might be turned off in the system which shows no error. Can you put a `var_dump($array)` before `foreach` and post the result here ? Debugging with @Darragh's suggestion also give some clues.

Comment: what version of PHP are you using json_encode/json_decode won't work in php versions < PHP 5.3

Comment: @b0s3 Thanks for your help.When you told me var_dump() function. Then I have used this function to print json data that I was getting from GET method.Then I find that json data was contained slashes. That was problem then I remove slashes using stripslashes($json). And I can do what I want...

Comment: Error reporting might be turned off in your XAMPP environment, please use `ini_set ("display_errors", "on");` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @Vanitas I got my mistake and resolved that problem and able to finish my job.Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer but an observation that your code is vulnerable to **SQL injection**. Try:

```
$sql = <<<EOF
INSERT IGNORE INTO 
  doctor_visit_track (id, doctor_name, doctor_email, date, time) VALUES 
  ('?', '?', '?', '?"', '?')")
EOF;

$stmt = mysqli_prepare( $con, $sql);

foreach ($array as $item){
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param( $stmt, "sssss",
      $item['id'], $item['doctorName'], $item['doctorEmail'],
      $item['date'],$item['time']
      );
    $result = mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    // rest of your code
};
```

Incidentally, you also had $con and $conn (2 'n') as your connect variable - hope you don't have this in your code.

I can't tell for certain but your code may be confusing the OO (object oriented) and procedural form of mysqli. Stick to one or the other (OO form ideally)

For example in your original code, say someone sent you a malicious JSON object similar to the following:

```
{
"id" : "hackerid",
"doctorName" : "I am a Hacker",
"doctorEmail": "hacker@hacker.com",
"date": "1999-12-31",
"time": "\"); drop table doctor_visit_track; -- Muhahahaha "
}
```

...you would not be happy with the result.

Comment: Thanks for telling me the mistake. I have fixed that mistake and make single connection $con variable. Actually I am not php guy..

Comment: As an example in your original code, if someone sends you an item in JSON where 'time' is *"); delete * from doctor_visit_track;"* they can wipe your doctor_visit_track table. Putting other stuff in here could wipe your whole database

Comment: Yes, but you have to debug it, I'm at work and haven't tested it obviously

Comment: Thanks I have used your code and also used php official documentation and able to do my work successfully..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that turned out to be due to PHP magic quotes being enabled, and adding escape characters to the json string.  Try disabling magic quotes in your php.ini:

magic_quotes_gpc = Off